# Append to the name of each file in directory

Tags: filenames

How to append “.backup” to the name of each file in your current directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have files with special characters and/or sub directories you should use:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv {} {}.backup \;
```

Answer (score 1):

This can do the trick

```
for FILE in $(find . -type f) ; do mv $FILE ${FILE}.backup ; done
```

Comment: This would append to all files below the current directory not just to the ones in the current directory.

Comment: Your answer only works if there are no spaces or newlines in the filenames. It also backs up all files in subdirectories of the current directory.

Comment: @Timo, space and newlines are not the only ones. tabs and all the wildcard characters (*, ?, [) are also a problem (except in `zsh`).

Answer (score 0):

With a POSIX shell:

```
for file in *;do
  [ -f "$file" ] && mv -- "$file" "$file.backup"
done
```

With `perl`'s `rename`:

```
rename -- '-f && s/\Z/.backup/' *
```

Comment: `*` doesn't include file names that start with a dot.